# Popup window after submit

Tags: c#, asp.net

Just to ask a straight question, when I complete adding some data in my page and click submit button, how can I make a popup window saying that the information has been successfully added in database instead of make a new page? Is there any ways that I can do? Any website to be referred? Thanks

Comment: Did you get any help from the answer?

Comment: Not yet. I am trying to go through 1 by 1 the suggested answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a re-usable function for it .

```
  public void Show(string msg)
  {
            Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
            if (page != null)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "msg", "alert('" + msg + "');", true);
            }
  }
```

and in submit button call like this.

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       // Your Code for submit 
        Show("Save Success");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to just put below code:

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('information has been successfully added')
                </script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set a label text with your message and make it visible when you want to show the message.

```
lblMessage.Text = "Data updated successfully";
lblMessage.Visible = true;
```

To make it prominent, you could use jquery [dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), and style it appropriately with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Global Declaration
public static void Message(String message, Control cntrl)
{
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(cntrl, cntrl.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + message + "');", true);
}


//Call any where, where you want to display message
 Message("Any message here", this);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Notification", "alert('Done');", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ASP.NET you would be still undergoing a full page life cycle if you are submitting your form with a regular submit behavior. This means that the page would first need to reload and then to fire your alert. If you want the page to not reload but instead just show a result alert, you would need to perform your action with AJAX, POSTing the form to a service method which updates the database you have. This would not reload your page and would just show an alert which your ajax call is complete. [jQuery $.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Answer (score 0):

On the click of your button after checking for valid data you can do something like this

```
ClientScriptManager script = Page.ClientScript

if (!script.IsStartupScriptRegistered(GetType(), "Show Popup"))
 {
   script.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Show Popup", "ShowPopup();", true);
 }
```

You can call `javascript` function from `code behind` using **[ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx)**

Here is you Popup

**HTML:**

```
<div id="Popup"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#Popup
{

    height:200px;
    width:300px;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:102;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-130px;
    margin-left:-180px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:10pt;
    padding:20px;
    background-color:#fff;
    border:10px solid #9cc3f7;
    border-radius:20px;
    -webkit-border-radius:20px;
    -moz-border-radius:20px;
    text-align:center;
    display:none;
}​
```

**Jquery function:**

```
function ShowPopup()
{

 $('#Popup').show("slow");

}​
```

**[See Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/vc5J5/)**